# Issues calling a function from a linked JS file using onclick from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, src

Im having issues calling a function from a linked .js file. In my html file I have a button that has the `onclick` set to call the function in the js file. Visual Studio tells me that the html and js files are linked correctly. Im using `document.getElementById("id").innerHTML` in the js file to change some text in the html file, but to no avail!

There is a couple of similar questions on here, from which I have tried implementing the advice in my own code, but still no joy.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Note: the two functions being called are at the very bottom of the .js file. I have left all the other code in there in case something is causing the issue.

```js
//Create array of objects
const person = [
    {
    name: 'Barry',
    age: 99,
    job: 'fisherman'},
    {
    name: 'Sally',
    age: 89,
    job: 'I.T. consultant'
    },
    {
    name: 'Gary',
    age: 79,
    job: 'wrestler'
    },
    {
    name: 'Mary',
    age: 69,
    job: 'political advisor'
    }];

    //Create Arrays
    const weather = ['sunny.', 'raining.', 'hot.', 'cold.', 'overcast.', 'stormy.'];
    const sport = ['tennis', 'football', 'snooker', 'golf', 'squash'];
    const food = ['cakes', 'apples', 'pies', 'fish', 'biscuits', 'crisps'];
    const location = ['beach', 'park', 'cliffs', 'wood', 'airport'];
    

    //Generate random number between 0 and passed array length
    const RandNumGen = (array) =>{
        const num = Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length);
        return num;
    }

    //Store random selection of each array in a variable
    let w = RandNumGen(weather)
    let s = RandNumGen(sport)
    let f = RandNumGen(food)
    let l = RandNumGen(location)

    //Store random selection of age,job & name
    let persName = RandNumGen(person);
    let persAge = RandNumGen(person);
    let persJob = RandNumGen(person);

    //Function to generate random message
    const mixMessage = () =>{
    document.getElementById("mix").innerHTML = person[persName].name + ' who is ' + person[persAge].age + ' and is an expert ' + person[persJob].job + ', enjoys playing ' + sport[s] + ' and eating ' + food[f] + ' at the ' + location[l] + ' when it is ' + weather[w];
    }

    //mixMessage()

    function test(){
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'please work';
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mixed Messages</title>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   
    <h1>Mixed Message Generator</h1>

    <p id="test">TEST</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="test()">TEST</button>

    <p id="mix">MIX</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="mixMessage()">Click me to generate a random message</button>
    


<footer id="footer">
    Copyright me 2021
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As the other users have already answered, `location` is causing the error. There are some reserved words in JavaScript. You cannot use them as identifiers. See details: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'location' has already been declared

`location` already exists as a global variable that can't be re-declared, as `window.location`. Use a different variable name, like `locations`. (It's an array, after all, so it should probably be plural).

```js
//Create array of objects
const person = [
    {
    name: 'Barry',
    age: 99,
    job: 'fisherman'},
    {
    name: 'Sally',
    age: 89,
    job: 'I.T. consultant'
    },
    {
    name: 'Gary',
    age: 79,
    job: 'wrestler'
    },
    {
    name: 'Mary',
    age: 69,
    job: 'political advisor'
    }];

    //Create Arrays
    const weather = ['sunny.', 'raining.', 'hot.', 'cold.', 'overcast.', 'stormy.'];
    const sport = ['tennis', 'football', 'snooker', 'golf', 'squash'];
    const food = ['cakes', 'apples', 'pies', 'fish', 'biscuits', 'crisps'];
    const locations = ['beach', 'park', 'cliffs', 'wood', 'airport'];
    

    //Generate random number between 0 and passed array length
    const RandNumGen = (array) =>{
        const num = Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length);
        return num;
    }

    //Store random selection of each array in a variable
    let w = RandNumGen(weather)
    let s = RandNumGen(sport)
    let f = RandNumGen(food)
    let l = RandNumGen(locations)

    //Store random selection of age,job & name
    let persName = RandNumGen(person);
    let persAge = RandNumGen(person);
    let persJob = RandNumGen(person);

    //Function to generate random message
    const mixMessage = () =>{
    document.getElementById("mix").innerHTML = person[persName].name + ' who is ' + person[persAge].age + ' and is an expert ' + person[persJob].job + ', enjoys playing ' + sport[s] + ' and eating ' + food[f] + ' at the ' + locations[l] + ' when it is ' + weather[w];
    }

    //mixMessage()

    function test(){
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'please work';
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mixed Messages</title>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   
    <h1>Mixed Message Generator</h1>

    <p id="test">TEST</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="test()">TEST</button>

    <p id="mix">MIX</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="mixMessage()">Click me to generate a random message</button>
    


<footer id="footer">
    Copyright me 2021
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

I'd also highly recommend [refactoring out the inline HTML attribute handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) and using `addEventListener` instead - it'll make the code more portable and will stop requiring global pollution for the script to work. Using that method, you'd be able to fix the problem a different way, by putting the whole script into an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Glossary/IIFE), so that the `location` you declared is not on the top level, thereby avoiding the error.

If the `person` array is dynamic, using `innerHTML` could be a security risk since that'll allow for arbitrary code execution, as the comment notes. Only use `innerHTML` when deliberately inserting or retrieving **HTML** markup. Otherwise, it's safer and more semantically appropriate to use `.textContent`, eg:

```
document.getElementById("mix").textContent = person[persName].name // ...
```

Comment: also recommend using `innerText` over `innerHTML` to help prevent XSS.

Answer (score 0):

Just do not use `location` since it is an existing global variable in the browser.

rename it to something else (I renamed it to `location1`) and it will work fine.

basically your script was having an error and that error keeps the script from loading.

```js
//Create array of objects
const person = [
    {
    name: 'Barry',
    age: 99,
    job: 'fisherman'},
    {
    name: 'Sally',
    age: 89,
    job: 'I.T. consultant'
    },
    {
    name: 'Gary',
    age: 79,
    job: 'wrestler'
    },
    {
    name: 'Mary',
    age: 69,
    job: 'political advisor'
    }];

    //Create Arrays
    const weather = ['sunny.', 'raining.', 'hot.', 'cold.', 'overcast.', 'stormy.'];
    const sport = ['tennis', 'football', 'snooker', 'golf', 'squash'];
    const food = ['cakes', 'apples', 'pies', 'fish', 'biscuits', 'crisps'];
    const location1 = ['beach', 'park', 'cliffs', 'wood', 'airport'];
    

    //Generate random number between 0 and passed array length
    const RandNumGen = (array) =>{
        const num = Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length);
        return num;
    }

    //Store random selection of each array in a variable
    let w = RandNumGen(weather)
    let s = RandNumGen(sport)
    let f = RandNumGen(food)
    let l = RandNumGen(location1)

    //Store random selection of age,job & name
    let persName = RandNumGen(person);
    let persAge = RandNumGen(person);
    let persJob = RandNumGen(person);

    //Function to generate random message
    const mixMessage = () =>{
    document.getElementById("mix").innerHTML = person[persName].name + ' who is ' + person[persAge].age + ' and is an expert ' + person[persJob].job + ', enjoys playing ' + sport[s] + ' and eating ' + food[f] + ' at the ' + location1[l] + ' when it is ' + weather[w];
    }

    //mixMessage()

    function test(){
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'please work';
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mixed Messages</title>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   
    <h1>Mixed Message Generator</h1>

    <p id="test">TEST</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="test()">TEST</button>

    <p id="mix">MIX</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="mixMessage()">Click me to generate a random message</button>
    


<footer id="footer">
    Copyright me 2021
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah i have got it working now. thanks very much! now to try and get it to generate the message on everyclick... quick question: how did you know of the error? when I ran it  no error was shown, but nothing happend on the click (the page loaded up fine).